# Java- How to read HTML of a website which requires login?

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a Java application which requires reading the html code of a website.  My issue is that the website I am attempting to read the html of requires a login (members.iracing.com - I do have a login for this site).  What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Calan Williams

Comment: That very much depends how exactly that website is actually implementing its check for credentials; thus it can be answered that easily.

Comment: I am attempting to read your code which requires an [mcve]

Comment: You'd need to figure out how they track session (usually using cookies) and then ensure that you emulate the same (Eg: you need remember the cookies and forward the same between requests). It may be a good idea to double check (if feasible, mail them) if doing it its fine though before you do so.